# "Ancient" mech, grandfather, morning exercise routine

Tags: story-identification

A young boy (possibly girl) doesn't understand grandfather's obsession with his morning exercise ritual, but it turns out it's a way to limber up the ancient mech that is needed to defend the village. Probably in one of the Year's Best anthologies...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you remember more details? Like, how long ago did you read this? Novel or short story?

Comment: I think it's one of the Bolo stories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Shining Armour* by Dominic Green, published in "The Mammoth Book of Best New SF 22" and originally in "The Solaris Book of Science Fiction 2"